# xlwings Range Error on Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: excel, macos, vba, python-2.7, xlwings

I just installed xlwings and was trying one of the examples and I am getting a Range error.  Other commands seem to work fine.  This is on Yosemite 10.10.3

Any Ideas what might be wrong?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> Sheet(1).name
u'Sheet1'
>>> Range('A1').value = 'Foo 1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 622, in __init__
    self.row2 = self.row1 + xlplatform.count_rows(self.xl_sheet, range_address) - 1
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 145, in count_rows
    return xl_sheet.cells[range_address].count(each=kw.row)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 431, in __call__
    raise TypeError('Unknown keyword argument %r.' % name)
TypeError: Unknown keyword argument 'each'.
>>>
```

Comment: Are you on Excel 2016?

Comment: Anyways, try again after upgrading to v0.3.6

Comment: I have the same error for excel 2016 and 2011.  Can I do the upgrade via pip?

Comment: Bingo that worked!  I removed xlwings 0.3.5 and reinstalled 0.3.6 and it worked on Excel 2016!